# Rotatelogs not functioning

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, logrotate

My system is Debian with Apache 2.22

I'm trying to rotate my logs with rotatelogs. The format in the logfile works but the rotation is not working.

Part of the apache2.conf

```
 LogFormat "%h %t %m %U %q %>s %B \"%{Referer}i\"" custom 
 CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/apache2/access_log 60" custom
```

Any mistakes here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things:

1. Apache log events

   ```
   LogFormat "%h %t %m %U %q %>s %B \"%{Referer}i\"" custom
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log custom
   ```
2. Logrotate log roratation

file /etc/logrotate.d/apache2

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
       daily
       missingok
       rotate 14
       compress
       delaycompress
       notifempty
       create 640 root adm
       sharedscripts
       postrotate
               if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                   /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
               fi;
       endscript
       prerotate
               if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                       run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
               fi; \
       endscript
}
```